# Python Return a Variable in the file

Tags: python, django, variables

I have tuple variables which are France, Germany. I'm trying to give a value to my bring_cities function and if it's France or Germany, I like to see the France and Germany tuple objects. Is there any shortcut to not use if loops like I did in the below ?

```
France = (
    ('Paris', 'Paris'),
    ('Lyon', 'Lyon'),
)
Germany = (
    ('Frankfurt', 'Frankfurt'),
    ('Berlin', 'Berlin'),
)

cities = (('', ''),) + France + Germany

def bring_cities(country): 
    if country == 'France':
        return France
    if country == 'Germany':
        return Germany
    ...
```

Comment: You could store the tuples in a dict and access them by key (country).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a dictionary so you don't have to write an if statement for each country. You can use the following code for that.

```
France = (
    ('Paris', 'Paris'),
    ('Lyon', 'Lyon'),
)
Germany = (
    ('Frankfurt', 'Frankfurt'),
    ('Berlin', 'Berlin'),
)

dictionary = {"France": France, "Germany": Germany}


def bring_cities(country):
    return dictionary[country]
```

to make it even shorter you can define your Countries inside the dictionary.

```
dictionary = {
              "France": (('Paris', 'Paris'), ('Lyon', 'Lyon')),
              "Germany": (('Frankfurt', 'Frankfurt'), ('Berlin', 'Berlin'),)
              }
```

Comment: thanks for your help gerda. there will be all countries and cities in my code. so is it possible to make it a bit shorter ?

Answer (score 0):

Resuming gerda's answer

```
France = (
    ('Paris', 'Paris'),
    ('Lyon', 'Lyon'),
)
Germany = (
    ('Frankfurt', 'Frankfurt'),
    ('Berlin', 'Berlin'),
)

dictionary = {"France": France, "Germany": Germany}


def bring_cities(country):
    print(dictionary[country])
    
user_choice = input("Enter a Country (France/Germany) and we will give you Cities in it: ")
bring_cities(user_choice)
```